# How does condition_variable::wait_for() deal with spurious wakeups?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, condition-variable, spurious-wakeup

[Spurious wakeup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spurious_wakeup) is allowed by various platforms. To counter that, we write below looping mechanism:

```
while(ContinueWaiting())
  cv.wait(lock);   // cv is a `std::conditional_variable` object
```

Same thing is understandable for `conditional_variable::wait_until()`.
But look at below example:

```
const auto duration = Returns_10_seconds();
while(!Predicate())
  cv.wait_for(lock, duration);
```

Imagine that, spurious wakeup happened at 1 second. Timeout is not yet reached.
Will it wait for another 10 seconds? This would lead to infinite loop, which I am sure should not happen. From source code, internally `wait_for()` calls `wait_until()`.

I want to understand, how does `wait_for()` deals with spurious wakeups?

Comment: It doesn't. You have to either check it yourself or use the overload that does it for you (the one that takes a predicate).

Comment: @MaiLongdong, the predicate is used to counter such wakeups only. Even `wait_for()` if it works fine in my platform, doesn't guarantee that it will work everywhere, because spurious wakesups are platform dependent.

Comment: If you don't want to `wait_for` 10 seconds use `wait_until` `now()` + 10 seconds :-)

Comment: @iammilind Well yes, hence my answer: `wait_for` doesn't deal with spurious wakeups. The user does.

Comment: @MaiLongdong, can you put it into an elaborated answer? It will be helpful to those who face this problem in real world.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I want to understand, how does `wait_for()` deals with spurious wakeups?

It doesn't.

This function is typically used in a situation where if you wake up spuriously, you want to do some other work anyway.  And if you don't wake up spuriously, you want to force a "spurious" wake up by the time `duration` has passed.  This means it is not typically used in a loop as you show, for exactly the reasons you state.  I.e. timeouts and spurious wake ups are treated *identically*.

Now you might be wondering, well, what does the predicate version do, as it implies a loop?

```
template <class Rep, class Period, class Predicate>
bool
wait_for(unique_lock<mutex>& lock, const chrono::duration<Rep, Period>& rel_time,
         Predicate pred);
```

This is specified to have the same effects as:

```
return wait_until(lock, chrono::steady_clock::now() + rel_time, std::move(pred));
```

The `wait_until` variation *does* distinguish between spurious wake ups and timeouts.  It does so with a loop like this:

```
while (!pred())
    if (wait_until(lock, abs_time) == cv_status::timeout)
        return pred();
return true;
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's what the standard has to say about spurious wakeups:

> **30.5 Condition variables [thread.condition]**
>
> Condition variables provide synchronization primitives used to block a thread until notified by some other
>   thread that some condition is met or until a system time is reached.
>
> ...
>
> 10 Note: It is the user’s responsibility to ensure that waiting threads
>   do not erroneously assume that the thread has finished if they
>   experience spurious wakeups.

From the wording it seems pretty clear that the responsibility for dealing with spurious wakeups is on the user.

Answer (score 1):

```
    const auto duration = Returns_10_seconds();
    while(cv.wait_for(lock, duration) == std::cv_status::timeout);
```

This is definitely a wrong thing to do and thus does not make sense discussing how to fix it for the case of spurious wakeups, as it is broken even for the case of ordinary wakeups, because the wait condition is not re-examined after returning from the wait.

```
const auto duration = Returns_10_seconds();
while(!Predicate())
  cv.wait_for(lock, duration);
```

Even after the edit, the answer stays the same: you can't really handle "spurious wakeups", because you can't really tell the reason for the wakeup - it may well be a completely legit wakeup due to a call to `condition_variable::notifyXXX` before the timeout has expired.

First, note that you can't really distinguish between a wakeup  caused by a call to `condition_variable::notifyXXX` and wakeup caused by, for example, a POSIX signal[1]. 
Second, even if POSIX signals are not of concern, the waiting thread still must reexamine the condition as it is possible for the condition to change between the time the condition variable is signaled and the waiting thread returns from the condition wait.

What you really have to do is treat in a special manner not waking up before the timeout, but waking up *due to timeout*. And that entirely depends on the reasons to have a timeout in the first place, i.e. on the  specifics of application/problem domain.

[1] if wait on a condition variable is interrupted by a signal, after executing the signal handler the thread is allowed either to resume wait or return

Comment: Your 1st para is right, actually I wrote it in the current way when I posted. After that, I changed it to what is there is [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/condition_variable/condition_variable/wait_for/). You may edit the answer according to current state of question.

Answer (score 1):

**Check supurious call yourself**

`cv.wait_for()` does not deal with spurious wakeups.

You can deal with spurious wakeups by passing a boolean flag to the thread by reference and check it when `cv.wait_until()` is not a timeout.

In this case when `main()` thread does not set `terminate` and `cv.wait_until()` has no_timeout, it means timeout is not reached but cv is notified (by system), and so it is a spurious call.

```
bool terminate = false;
std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mutex);
const auto time_point = std::chrono::system_clock::now() + std::chrono::seconds(10);
const std::cv_status status = cv.wait_until(lock, time_point);
if (status == std::cv_status::timeout) {
    std::cout << "timeout" << std::endl;
}
else { // no_timeout
    if (terminate) {
        std::cout << "terminate" << std::endl;
        break;
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "spurious" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

**Full Code**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <chrono>

class Thread {
private:
    std::condition_variable cv;
    std::mutex mutex;
    bool terminate = false;
    std::thread thread;
public:
    Thread() {
        thread = std::thread([&]() {
            while (true) {
                std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mutex);
                const auto time_point = std::chrono::system_clock::now() + std::chrono::seconds(10);
                const std::cv_status status = cv.wait_until(lock, time_point);
                if (status == std::cv_status::timeout) {
                    std::cout << "timeout" << std::endl;
                }
                else { // no_timeout
                    if (terminate) {
                        std::cout << "terminate" << std::endl;
                        break;
                    }
                    else {
                        std::cout << "spurious" << std::endl;
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
    virtual ~Thread() {
        {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mutex);
            terminate = true;
        }
        cv.notify_all();
        if (thread.joinable()) {
            thread.join();
        }
    }
};

void main() {
    {
        Thread thread;
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(15));
    }
    std::cin.get();
}
```

**Full Code Result when main() sleep_for()**

```
5 seconds:
terminate

15 seconds:
timeout
terminate

15 seconds in Visual Studio Debug mode:
spurious
terminate
```

Answer (score 1):

I have the same concern, but I checked the source code, it seems both wait_for and wait_until could handle spurious wakeups, could anyone correct me if I am wrong?

```
template<typename _Clock, typename _Duration, typename _Predicate>
  bool
  wait_until(unique_lock<mutex>& __lock,
     const chrono::time_point<_Clock, _Duration>& __atime,
     _Predicate __p)
  {
while (!__p())
  if (wait_until(__lock, __atime) == cv_status::timeout)
    return __p();
return true;
  }

template<typename _Rep, typename _Period>
  cv_status
  wait_for(unique_lock<mutex>& __lock,
       const chrono::duration<_Rep, _Period>& __rtime)
  {
using __dur = typename __steady_clock_t::duration;
auto __reltime = chrono::duration_cast<__dur>(__rtime);
if (__reltime < __rtime)
  ++__reltime;
return wait_until(__lock, __steady_clock_t::now() + __reltime);
  }
```